# Efficient way to prune HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap, pruning

I am creating a Flyweight in Java, and I want to make sure I don't create too large a map.   Is there a more efficient way to prune the map?  I did not see any properties that could do this automatically (like a max size constructor), so I am doing it in code.

Here is what I have, its pretty basic, but I want to make sure there isn't a better way:

```
private static void prune() {
    Iterator<Entry<Integer, Integer[]>> iterator =  seeds.entrySet().iterator();
    int removed = 0;
    while(iterator.hasNext()|| removed == pruneLength) {
        iterator.next();
        iterator.remove();
        removed++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you're trying to avoid a map that has a wide spread of keys or?

Comment: Why not use `iterator.remove()`? It reflects back on the map.

Comment: I want to limit this maps growth over time.  I shouldn't hit this limit often...

Comment: Do not use an `Iterator` and remove (or add) elements in the active list while you are iterating on it - it leads to unspecified behaviour for the iterator. Use the `iterator.remove()` method instead. (cf. http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html ))

Comment: @Donal Fellows  I have updated my post to reflect using .remove()

Comment: @Nix: How do you choose which elements should be pruned? What elements does your Map represent that they can be pruned without regard to their contents?

Comment: You have to call `iterator.next()` before you call `iterator.remove()` - that method removes the last element returned.

Comment: I will most likely prune the oldest(oldest access time) element in the list. (copy paste error, i removed the next() by accident)

Comment: Doesn't look very safe to me...

Comment: No need to over engineer this, this is just a utility app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LinkedHashMap can used as a LRU cache.

```
Map<Integer, Integer[]> map = createLRUMap(128);

public static <K, V> Map<K, V> createLRUMap(final int maxSize) {
    return new LinkedHashMap<K,V>(maxSize, 1, true) {
        @Override
        protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry<K,V> eldest) {
            return size() > maxSize;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: I am testing this one out now.

Comment: it uses builtin/tested code, and it impliments LRU very simply.

Comment: Opps, slight bug as it will remove the last element when it matched the maximum size rather when it was larger than the max size.

Answer (score 4):

[Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com)'s [MapMaker](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html) has this in its latest version (on trunk). It should be in r08, though I don't know when that's coming out exactly.

```
ConcurrentMap<Integer, Integer[]> seeds = new MapMaker()
     .maximumSize(maxSize)
     .makeMap();
```

Note that this is a thread-safe concurrent map, which seems like it might be important depending on how you're using it.

Comment: `// MapMaker, MapMaker, make me a map...`

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using caches, [EhCache](http://ehcache.org/) for example? They implement maps and declaratively you can set the size, limit after values are stored on a disk etc.

Comment: This is a pretty small project, I dont think there is a need to take it to the EhCache level.  Thank you for the suggestion though... i will keep this in mind for future projects.

Comment: ehcache is a very nice library. However I always prefer to start simple if possible.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility from the world of databases is to have two (or potentially more maps). Lookups use both maps. Writes to just one. When the one being written hits capacity, replace/clear the read-only map and switch.